# I want to change the font awesome icon like stars color to red (default is black) without using vanilla CSS

Tags: css, font-awesome, bootstrap-5

```
<div>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                </div>
```

I want to change the fonts to red color without using vanilla CSS. what should be the class in bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `.text-danger` to the containing element.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.3/css/all.min.css">


<div class="text-danger">
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/colors/

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Bootstrap 5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/colors/). The `text-danger` class is red, so this can be used where ever you want red text..

`<i class="fas fa-star text-danger"></i>`